# Distributing gfortran-compiled binary to Mac OS X users who don't have Xcode?

Tags: gfortran

I'm teaching a class in which I would like students to run a precompiled command-line program on their own laptops.  Some students have Windows; others have Mac.  I was able to create a self-contained binary that the Windows users can just drop into their working directory and run.

To my surprise, I'm finding it far more difficult to do the same thing for Mac users.  In particular, it appears to be impossible to compile a standalone binary program with all required libraries statically linked. The particular libraries that need to be present are libgfortran and libquadmath, since the gfortran compiler is used to compile the legacy F77 code (and it's too big a program to convert to another language).

So the only potentially workable solution I've found so far is for students to first install Xcode, then Xcode's command line tools, and finally gfortran on their own computer before my executable will find the gfortran library and run.  But this is way too much work (and disk space) for what I want them to do.

My question: is there a way I'm overlooking to compile my program in *completely* self-contained form? Obviously it's hard for me to experiment, because it involves other people's computers.

EDIT:  I found the following post which describes essentially the same problem:   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/TPEQQEwa0HI
Unfortunately, the solution given doesn't work for me, even after I delete some options and make appropriate substitutions.

Comment: What has Xcode have to do with Fortran libraries? The Fortran compiler is completely independent of any IDE. The relevant libraries may be distributed with the compiled binary.

Comment: The only way I'm aware of to install gfortran requires the installation first of Xcode and of Xcode's command-line tools.  If there's another way, I'd like to hear about it.

Comment: I do not have a Mac but most mac people here appear to use something called [tag:homebrew]. There is always the source code at gcc.org...

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think even homebrew requires Xcode and command-line tools.
Edit:  here's a link.  https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

Comment: It only explicitly mentions the command line tools But whatever, Mac is weird, blame Apple.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you linked to includes the -static-libgfortran, but not -static-libgcc, so it may be worth adding the second of these.

For a barebones Hello World code, I get:

```
[~] oldrabbit $ otool -L a.out 
a.out:
    /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/8/libgfortran.5.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
    /usr/local/lib/gcc/8/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/8/libquadmath.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
[~] oldrabbit $ gfortran -static-libgfortran -static-libgcc hello.f90 
[~] oldrabbit $ otool -L a.out 
a.out:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
    /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/8/libquadmath.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

so looks like the libquadmath library might still be a problem.  If you can find the path to the .a version of that, you could try including it like in the example you linked to.

Comment: The problem with the solution I linked to is that I was getting ld errors ('duplicate symbols').  If I left libquadmath out, I got the error that that library wasn't found.  If I put it in, I got the 'duplicate symbol' errors.  I'm by no means an ld guru, but I was unable to find a combination that worked.

Answer (score 0):

a solution would be to ship the executable **and** the libquadmath by using `install_name_tool`:

```
cp -f /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_4/lib/gcc/10/libquadmath.0.dylib .
install_name_tool -change $i @executable_path/libquadmath.0.dylib a.out
```

Of course the second command must be done every time you recompile your binary